# Difference between F-Automorphism and Identity morphism

Tags: group-theory, galois-theory

In reading Shiffrin *Abstract Algebra*, in the section on Galois Theory, it gives the following definition:

For *K* a field extension of *F*, a ring isomorphism $\phi:K\to K$ is an **F-Automorphism** if

$\phi(a) = a$, $\forall  a \in F$

My question is, how is this different from the identity morphism? Isn't (by this definition) the set of all F-automorphisms, or the Galois group, just the identity mapping? I'm slightly confused.

Thank you very much!

Comment: The identity map on $\color{Red}{K}$ is defined by $\phi(a)=a,\forall a\in\color{Red}{K}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that the *restriction of $\phi$ to $F$* is the identity morphism on $F$.  The definition doesn't say anything about what $\phi$ should do to the rest of $K$ (other than be a bijective homorphism, of course).  It may not be true that $\phi$ fixes the rest of $K$.  For example, complex conjugation is an $\mathbb{R}$-automorphism of $\mathbb{C}$.

Answer (score 1):

Even though elements of $F$ are fixed, $F$-automorphisms can send elements of $K$\ $F$ to other such elements of $K$.  For example, in $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]$, one such $\mathbb{Q}$-automorphism could send $\sqrt{2} \mapsto -\sqrt{2}$.  In fact, this is the only nontrivial $\mathbb{Q}$-automorphism of this extension.

P.S. I'm learning from Shifrin's text too. :)